# Cannot create other references of instances in method

Tags: java, methods, reference

I'm making a calculator program in Eclipse as an excersize.  I am getting lots of errors. What I would like to do is "change the name" of the two references `this` and `dec` to make the code more clear later in the method. What is the problem?

```
public Decimals plus(Decimals dec) {
    //let's get the length of the 2 numbers
    int this_len=this.getLength(), dec_len=dec.getLength();
    int longest_len;
    //to simplify the code the two numbers are called long or short
    Decimals short; //shortest   <-- Syntax error on token 'short', ++ expected / Decimals cannot be resolved to a variable
    Decimals long; //longest   <-- Syntax error on token 'long', ++ expected / Decimals cannot be resolved to a variable
    if (this_len >= dec_len){
        short = dec;   // <-- Syntax error on token "=", delete this token / Duplicate local variable dec
        long = this;  // <-- Syntax error on token "long", invalid Expression
        longest_len = this_len; 
    }
    else {
        short = this; // <-- Syntax error on token "short", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
        long = dec; //  <-- Syntax error on token "long", invalid Expression
        longest_len = dec_len;
    }
```

Comment: `short` and `long` are primitives. Can't use primitives as variable names

Comment: `short` and `long` are keywords in Java.  They are reserved by the language and you can't use them as variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`short` and `long` are keywords. You can't use them as variable names. `shortest` and `longest` would be fine.

Comment: Thank you, I would have never thought about this